# Mixed return types in UML

Tags: uml

I'm documenting a system where some functions have mixed return types (`bool` or `T`), or act as a proxy for another method. How would I represent this in UML?

Comment: I looked around on the stack exchange directory, but couldn't see a better place for this. Vote to move it if you know somewhere better, please.

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com they like non-programming programming-related questions